# Java uploading to Imgur?

Tags: java, imgur

I know there are other posts on this but they don't seem to work for me or are outdated.

What I'm trying to do is to upload a **BufferedImage** object to **Imgur** and then get the direct URL. However, **DuckDuckGo** is letting me down on this one.

Does anyone have a class for this or something?

Comment: Are you trying to upload image to database or just the image to a directory and then image url or name to database. what java tech. are you using. servlets or swing.  Again can i see your code. i mean your effort so far so that i can help you.

Comment: I tried some things I found online but they were outdated and used the old API so I removed it. At this point I just have a BufferedImage which I want to upload to Imgur and the get the URL (example: https://i.imgur/idk.png) to use it online.

Comment: Have you considered [checking the documentation](http://api.imgur.com/) ?

Comment: @CtpBartender I did but I couldn't get it to work myself. That's why I asked if someone made a class or something for it.